# Oracle SQL to find all eligible transactions against specific value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to find all eligible lines which can be billed against specific amount (Available balance based on the limit).

Sample Data:

```
ITEM    AMOUNT  
1       30      
2       40      
3       60      
4       -60     
5       20      
6       20      
7       5       
8       35
```

Let's say available balance is 100 to billed. I want below lines to be picked where I marked Elig_For_Inv = Y. Please note that Item# 3 is marked with Y because next line is credit and it bring downs the total. Also requirement is to find eligible items in Item# ascending order.

```
ITEM    AMOUNT  ELIG_FOR_INV
1       30      Y
2       40      Y
3       60      Y
4       -60     Y
5       20      Y
6       20      N
7       5       Y
8       35      N
```

30+40+60-60+20+5=95 < 100

I tried to mark eligible items using running total and compare that with available balance.

```
 with t1 as (select 1 item, 30 amount from dual 
 union select 2 item, 40 amount from dual 
 union select 3 item, 60 amount from dual 
 union select 4 item, -60 amount from dual 
 union select 5 item, 20 amount from dual
 union select 6 item, 20 amount from dual 
 union select 7 item, 5 amount from dual 
 union select 8 item, 35 amount from dual ) 
 select t1.*, 
 CASE
   WHEN 100 - SUM ( amount ) over ( order by item rows unbounded preceding ) >= 0 THEN 'Y' 
 ELSE 'N' 
 END Elig_For_Inv from t1;
```

I'm getting below output.

```
ITEM    AMOUNT  ELIG_FOR_INV
1       30      Y
2       40      Y
3       60      N
4       -60     Y
5       20      Y
6       20      N
7       5       N
8       35      N
```

Expected Output:

```
ITEM    AMOUNT  ELIG_FOR_INV
1       30      Y
2       40      Y
3       60      Y
4       -60     Y
5       20      Y
6       20      N
7       5       Y
8       35      N
```

Comment: Can be done recursively ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n5hoHvcq)), but I don't know how _credit line_ works, I summed them at first.

Comment: @PonderStibbons -- please make this an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: But it requires explanation if we can subtract credits at the beginning or if only it is following line with same value or what. Please use my dbfiddle, as I cannot continue today.

Comment: *Please note that Item# 3 is marked with Y because next line is credit and it bring downs the total*: I don't get the logic here. How do you want these credit lines to be processed?

Comment: @GMB -- the logic looks to be that you can go over 100 for a given item if the next item is negative and covers the amount it exceeds 100 (130 < 160 in this case)

Comment: credits needs to be considered in sequence of item#. It can be following line or random line at different number(e.g. after 4-5 lines down). only criteria here is to bill oldest transactions first.  We do not need to consider credit line if we already hit the limit and credit line is not on following line!

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row processing:

```sql
SELECT item, amount, elig_for_inv
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY item
  MEASURES
    classifier() AS ELIG_FOR_INV
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( ^ (Y|N)+ )
  DEFINE
    Y AS SUM(Y.amount) + LEAST(COALESCE(NEXT(Y.amount), 0), 0) <= 100
      OR SUM(Y.amount) + Y.amount <= 100,
    N AS SUM(Y.amount) + N.amount > 100
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ITEM, AMOUNT) AS
SELECT 1,  30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, -60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,   5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8,  35 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ITEM | AMOUNT | ELIG_FOR_INV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | Y |
| 2 | 40 | Y |
| 3 | 60 | Y |
| 4 | -60 | Y |
| 5 | 20 | Y |
| 6 | 20 | N |
| 7 | 5 | Y |
| 8 | 35 | N |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bGaIWTSj)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT item, amount, elig_for_inv
FROM   table_name
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY (item)
  MEASURES (
    amount,
    0 AS y_amount,
    'N' AS elig_for_inv
  )  
  RULES AUTOMATIC ORDER (
    elig_for_inv[item] =
      CASE
      WHEN COALESCE(y_amount[cv()-1], 0)
           + amount[cv()]
           + COALESCE(LEAST(amount[cv() + 1], 0), 0)
           <= 100
      THEN 'Y'
      ELSE 'N'
      END,
    y_amount[item] =
      CASE
      WHEN elig_for_inv[cv()] = 'Y'
      THEN amount[cv()]
      ELSE 0
      END + COALESCE(y_amount[cv()-1], 0)
  );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ITEM, AMOUNT) AS
SELECT 1,  30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, -60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,   5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8,  35 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ITEM | AMOUNT | ELIG_FOR_INV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | Y |
| 2 | 40 | Y |
| 3 | 60 | Y |
| 4 | -60 | Y |
| 5 | 20 | Y |
| 6 | 20 | N |
| 7 | 5 | Y |
| 8 | 35 | N |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-jj_FYJp)